# Meaning of '??' operator in php

Tags: php

what is the meaning of '??' operator in php?
I've seen someone using it like this. I've searched many results in google. But didn't found any solution.

`$this->variable = $arg['value'] ?? NULL`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: @tkausl Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`??` is the new (since PHP 7) [NULL coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). If the first argument is set and is not null it is returned, otherwise, the second argument is returned.